# Use the result of a loop statement as a combobox's rowsource

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to make the rowsource of a combobox the results of a loop statement.

```
Dim intDay As Date

For intDay = BegDate To EndDate
    If Format(intDay, "ddd") = "Sat" Then
    Debug.Print intDay
    End If
Next intDay
```

The loop returns all Saturdays between a period. The dates are in a table field named WDATE so I wanted BegDate and EndDate to be something like Min(WDATE) and Max(WDATE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never check literal weekdays or monthnames as these are localised.

Your loop could look:

```vb
Dim WeekdayDate As Date

For WeekdayDate = BegDate To EndDate
    If Weekday(WeekdayDate) = vbSaturday Then
        Debug.Print WeekdayDate
    End If
Next
```

However, such combo/listboxes can be better build using a little known *gem* of Access: *Callback* functions.

Study both simple and extended examples in my project:

[VBA.Callback](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Callback).

The last example covers your case (and a bit more).

Comment: wow, those functions are way over my head, but yes the last example does exactly what I want.

Comment: It looks worse than it is. The examples in the [first article](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/35774/Callback-functions-in-Microsoft-Access-VBA-Part-1.html?preview=KkyJtTCvMUs%3D) linked are easy-going.